# What library to load to stop typing Console. ... every time

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Writing out `Console.Read` or `Console.Write` every single time has been annoying me with this project. I know there is a library to load to take out the `Console` part so that I can just type `ReadLine()`.

Anyone know what it is? I have forgotten.

Thank you!

Comment: `using static System.Console;`

Comment: I often create a function void log(string text) with a few overloads; much more flexible..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a library, from C# 6 and onwards you can use a "static using directive":

```
using static System.Console;

...

WriteLine("Test"); // Console. is assumed
```

Here are some links with more information:

- [How C# 6.0 Simplifies, Clarifies and Condenses Your Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx)
- [using Directive (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Note that you have to give the full qualified name of the type in the `using` directive, so `using static Console` is not enough.

Comment: Your'e correct- sorry wrong wording! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is a feature called "static using directive" introduced in C# 6.0:

```
using static System.Console;
```

MSDN on [static using directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx):

> To allow you to access static members of a type without having to qualify the access with the type name:
>   `using static System.Math;`

*More about C# 6.0 features in: [How C# 6.0 Simplifies, Clarifies and Condenses Your Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx)*